# Why is location/size changed automatically in Windows Forms Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, code-generation

I have made a code generator to generate a WinForms application. However, the location and size of every object is changed automatically when I open a specific form in Visual studio 2012 for the first time.

The ratio of the change is around 1,12 to 1,25 times smaller. Other forms that are not opened in Visual Studio will not be changed, they keep the same location and size set in my generator.

I click "Save All" to save all the changes to disk. However, when I open those forms after building the application, they show the same locations even though the location and size of forms which I clicked "Open" on Visual Studio have now 1,12 to 1,25 times smaller than the files which have not been opened on Visual studio (I checked those files with Notepad++ to compare all objects).

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: At the very least, you need to post the generated code and the changes that VS does

Comment: Here is an example which is generated by code generator:                              
            this.tabCtrMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(135, 55);
            this.tabCtrMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1533, 781);

Comment: After the form is opened in Visual Studio, location and size are changed as below:   
            this.tabCtrMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 44);
            this.tabCtrMain.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 2, 3, 2);
            this.tabCtrMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1363, 625);